# What's the right way to map git branches to a kubernetes namespaces in CI?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I want to associate git branches to kubernetes namespaces, for my Gitlab CI pipeline to deploy helm charts to the right namespaces, based on the branch. For example:

```
master branch  -> prd namespace
devel branch   -> dev namespace
```

**How do I map branches to namespaces?**

I tried some simple bash logic in the CI script and Gitlab CI variables. Both work but both are kludges. I’d like to know what the correct, non-“makeshift” way to do something like this is.

Someone knowledgeable suggested to use a helm values file for each namespace like values_prd.yaml/values_dev.yaml (I believe what they meant was to use a values file for each branch, values_master.yaml/values_devel.yaml) but neither option makes sense to me right now, as I don’t believe you can’t tell helm what namespace to install charts to by passing values
(can you?).

Here’s my [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/tpfinalcraftech/test-app-frontend/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml).

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but deployment-/CD-related, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There are specialized (CD-)Tools to do this. For example, achieving the desired result is straightforward with [argocd](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Oh alright. Should I delete it?

Comment: That is for you to decide :)